# How to loop over dict(Python) in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

This may be something very trivial for most of you with a PowerShell background but I am coming from python so finding it a little difficult to understand on how things work in Powershell.

I have the following dict, created by some other python func which looks like following -

```
data = {
 'test1@gmail.com': ['a@gmail.com', 'b@gmail.com'], 
 'test2@gmail.com': ['c@gmail.com'], 
 'test3@gmail.com': ['d@gmail.com', 'e@gmail.com']
 }
```

I want to take this data and loop through it in Powershell in such a way that the output should print

```
Key test1@gmail.com has a@gmail.com value
Key test1@gmail.com has b@gmail.com value
Key test2@gmail.com has c@gmail.com value
Key test3@gmail.com has d@gmail.com value
Key test3@gmail.com has e@gmail.com value
```

The first problem I am facing is I am not sure how to save the `data` variable in PowerShell I tried `@` as well but was unable to figure it out. Any help from those with PowerShell backgrounds would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the code below:

```
$data = "{
 'test1@gmail.com': ['a@gmail.com', 'b@gmail.com'], 
 'test2@gmail.com': ['c@gmail.com'], 
 'test3@gmail.com': ['d@gmail.com', 'e@gmail.com']
 }"

 $x = $data | ConvertFrom-Json

 foreach($a in $x.psobject.properties){

 foreach($b in $a.Value){
 $str = "Key " + $a.Name + " has " + $b
 $str
 }
 
}

 "**completed"
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.